# Elementary Differential Geometry before Manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, self-learning, advice

Many courses called Differential Geometry (at least in Germany; at least as far as I know!) solely deal with manifolds and not classical/elementary Differential Geometry (curves, curvature, fundamental forms, ...).

So my simple question is: Should you study Elementary Differential Geometry before having a serious go at manifolds?

Comment: Should? No. Can? If you want. You should have some (basic) familiarity with the tools of analyis however, such as the derivative of a map $\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^m$.

Comment: About basic analysis tools: Sure. I don't know why anybody would be interested in manifolds before knowing basic analysis.

Comment: Before you have a go at manifolds, not necessarily. I'm personally fond of Guillemin and Pollack's differential topology text, which works exclusively with submanifolds of $\Bbb R^n$. However, if you're going to take a sophisticated course in differential geometry (connections and curvature), then by all means get some intuition for it by first studying (curves and) surfaces. Otherwise, it's pretty sophisticated and often unmotivated.

Comment: For geometry, say, the classical groups are really basic, like $SO(n)$ for example. Then one should know what a group is, and also what a Lie group is (hence what a manifold is). Actually, I encountered $SO(3)$ even before basic analysis with maps $\Bbb R^n\rightarrow \Bbb R^m$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1377089/differential-geometry-in-the-context-of-manifolds?rq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2845605/learning-differentiable-manifolds-prior-to-classical-differential-geometry?rq=1

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Good to know, thanks! Great textbook you‘ve written by the way, it‘s actually exactly the one I would use were I to study Elementary Differential Geometry.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde Hm, one of my main motivations to study manifolds at the moment actually is to understand Lie Groups. Of course, I did encounter groups like $SO(3)$ in Linear Algebra already but ultimately I want some understanding in Representation Theory of Lie Algebras.

Comment: @Kezer Sure we did. Physics student may have encountered definition of manifolds and metric before they even know basic analysis.

Comment: @Sou Do you now learn those hand it hand? I mean sure, metric spaces are quite elementary - in Germany they are usually defined at the beginning of the 2nd semester in Analysis 2. Sometimes submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are defined in the 2nd semester as well but I thought you needed a bit of basic analysis for this?

Comment: It depends what are we looking. If someone want to study manifolds and its aparatus rigorously, he doesn't have a choice other than get to know some analysis in $R^n$ to feel comfortable when studying manifolds. But for physics student, most of them just have a vague idea of manifolds.

Comment: Hm, perhaps we interpret basic analysis differently - I'm thinking physics student will at least know a little bit about multi-dimensional differentiation, etc. before hearing about manifolds? Possibly that's not what you meant by basic analysis, though.